# apt-get -f install getting disk space error in-spite of space

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, ubuntu

I want to set cloudwatch alerts on my production server but getting dependency errors for libwww-perl while resolving it is saying  "No space left on device" though there is space. please let me know what is that I am missing.

ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-17:/opt/aws-scripts-mon$ ./mon-put-instance-data.pl

```
Can't locate URI/Escape.pm in @INC (you may need to install the URI::Escape module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 /usr/share/perl/5.22 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base . .) at AwsSignatureV4.pm line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at AwsSignatureV4.pm line 20.
Compilation failed in require at CloudWatchClient.pm line 21.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at CloudWatchClient.pm line 21.
Compilation failed in require at ./mon-put-instance-data.pl line 86.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./mon-put-instance-data.pl line 86.
```

ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-17:/opt/aws-scripts-mon$ sudo apt-get install libwww-perl libdatetime-perl -y

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdatetime-perl : Depends: libdatetime-locale-perl but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libdatetime-timezone-perl (>= 1:1.74) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libparams-validate-perl (>= 1.03) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libtry-tiny-perl but it is not going to be installed
 libwww-perl : Depends: libencode-locale-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libfile-listing-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libhtml-parser-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libhtml-tagset-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libhtml-tree-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libhttp-cookies-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libhttp-date-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libhttp-message-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libhttp-negotiate-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: liblwp-mediatypes-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: liblwp-protocol-https-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libnet-http-perl (>= 6.07) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: liburi-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libwww-robotrules-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libhtml-form-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libhtml-format-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libhttp-daemon-perl but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libmailtools-perl but it is not going to be installed
 linux-headers-4.4.0-157-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-157 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-17:/opt/aws-scripts-mon$ sudo apt-get -f install

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-101 linux-headers-4.4.0-101-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-103 linux-headers-4.4.0-103-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-104 linux-headers-4.4.0-104-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-108
  linux-headers-4.4.0-108-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-109 linux-headers-4.4.0-109-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-112 linux-headers-4.4.0-112-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-116
  linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-119 linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-121 linux-headers-4.4.0-121-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-124
  linux-headers-4.4.0-124-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-127 linux-headers-4.4.0-127-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-128 linux-headers-4.4.0-128-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-130
  linux-headers-4.4.0-130-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-133 linux-headers-4.4.0-133-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-134 linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-137
  linux-headers-4.4.0-137-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-138 linux-headers-4.4.0-138-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-139 linux-headers-4.4.0-139-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-141
  linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-142 linux-headers-4.4.0-142-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-143 linux-headers-4.4.0-143-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-148
  linux-headers-4.4.0-148-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-150 linux-headers-4.4.0-150-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-59 linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-66
  linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70 linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-71 linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-75 linux-headers-4.4.0-75-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-78 linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-79 linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-81
  linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-83 linux-headers-4.4.0-83-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-87 linux-headers-4.4.0-87-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-89 linux-headers-4.4.0-89-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-91 linux-headers-4.4.0-91-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-92 linux-headers-4.4.0-92-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-93 linux-headers-4.4.0-93-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-96
  linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-97 linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-98 linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic linux-image-4.4.0-104-generic linux-image-4.4.0-108-generic linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-133-generic linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic linux-image-4.4.0-137-generic linux-image-4.4.0-138-generic linux-image-4.4.0-139-generic linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-142-generic linux-image-4.4.0-143-generic linux-image-4.4.0-148-generic linux-image-4.4.0-150-generic linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-75-generic linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic linux-image-4.4.0-87-generic linux-image-4.4.0-89-generic linux-image-4.4.0-91-generic linux-image-4.4.0-92-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-143-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-148-generic
  linux-modules-4.4.0-150-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-157
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-157
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 164 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/10.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 71.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 1293295 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-4.4.0-157_4.4.0-157.185_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-157 (4.4.0-157.185) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-157_4.4.0-157.185_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-157/Kbuild.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-157/Kbuild'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the **error message indicates a disk full error**
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-4.4.0-157_4.4.0-157.185_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-17:/opt/aws-scripts-mon$ df -h

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         395M   46M  350M  12% /run
/dev/xvda1                     20G   13G  6.4G  67% /
tmpfs                         2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                         2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cassandra-volume  200G  6.4G  194G   4% /var/lib/cassandra
tmpfs                         395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Your inode usage could be high. Check with `df -i`.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-21-0-14:/opt/aws-scripts-mon$ df -i
Filesystem                      Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                            503264     376    502888    1% /dev
tmpfs                           505575     506    505069    1% /run
/dev/xvda1                     1310720 1306201      4519  100% /
tmpfs                           505575       1    505574    1% /dev/shm

Comment: tmpfs                           505575       4    505571    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                           505575      16    505559    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/cassandra-volume 104853504    1823 104851681    1% /var/lib/cassandra
tmpfs                           505575       4    505571    1% /run/user/1000

Comment: @linuxartisan yes you are right 100 IUse% now what can be done as this production Cassandra DB

Comment: You need to find some old files and delete them. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inode usage is high. Which basically means that you have a lot of small files on your server (since disk is still not full).

So you need to find these small files and delete old / not required ones.

Meanwhile, as a quick workaround, you may try autoremoving unneeded packages.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

or

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Note: This is **not a permanent solution**. It's just a quick fix.

You are bound to face this problem time and again, unless you find where these small files are getting created and write a `cron job` to periodically delete them.

Comment: how to find these small files and delete old / not required ones?

Comment: root@ip-172-21-0-17:/tmp# for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l | sort -hr | head ; done
/bin
172
/boot
515
/dev
378
/etc
2076
/home
24
/initrd.img
1
/initrd.img.old
1
/lib
54688
/lib64
2
/lost+found
1
/media
1
/mnt
1
/opt
16508
/proc
find: ‘/proc/8225’: No such file or directory
683545
/root
74
/run
510
/sbin
225
/snap
2
/srv
1
/sys
37139
/tmp
28
/usr
1227642
/var
12655
/vmlinuz
1
/vmlinuz.old
1
root@ip-172-21-0-17:/tmp# ls -i /usr/
bin/     games/   include/ lib/     local/   sbin/    share/   src/

Comment: root@ip-172-21-0-17:/tmp# ls -i /usr/
105 bin  106 games  107 include  108 lib  109 local  110 sbin  111 share  112 src
root@ip-172-21-0-17:/tmp# for i in /usr/*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l | sort -hr | head ; done
/usr/bin
882
/usr/games
1
/usr/include
2247
/usr/lib
11276
/usr/local
716
/usr/sbin
159
/usr/share
25678
/usr/src
1186682

Comment: root@ip-172-21-0-17:/tmp# sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-4.4.0-157-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-157 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.